# How can I delete a row from .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am a new  learner in python trying to understand the logic and the solution of this problem.Exercise says to create an order app for a coffee shop .

```
 import uuid  # GET A RANDOM ID FOR THE CUSTOMER
    from datetime import date  # GET CURRENT DATE
    from csv import DictWriter
    inlist = -1
    length = 0
    Total_Amount = 0.0
    CustomerList = []
    AddressList = []
    Today_Key = date.toordinal(date.today())
    Today_Date = date.today()
    Print_Today = Today_Date
    Customers = {}
    Dates = {}
    FirstEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee1"
    FirstEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop1"
    SecondEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee2"
    SecondEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop2"
    ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee3"
    ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop3"
    
    print("Welcome to our coffee shop!")
    print("Login")
    
    # EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS STARTS
    LoginEnter = True
    while LoginEnter:
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        if username == FirstEmployeeAccountUsername and password == FirstEmployeeAccountPassword or username == SecondEmployeeAccountUsername and password == SecondEmployeeAccountPassword or username == ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername and password == ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword:
            print("Login Successful")
            LoginEnter = False
        else:
            print("Invalid Login. Try again")
    # EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCESS ENDS
    
    # PROCESS AFTER ORDER PLACEMENT STARTS
    process1 = True
    process2 = True
    while process1:
        while process2:
            Customer_Name = input("Customer's Name:")
            CustomerList.append(Customer_Name)
            Customers_Address = input("Customer's Address:")
            AddressList.append(Customers_Address)
            if Today_Key not in Dates:
                Dates[Today_Key] = {}
                if Customer_Name not in Dates[Today_Key]:
                    Dates[Today_Key][Customer_Name] = 1
                else:
                    Dates[Today_Key][Customer_Name] += 1
    
            if Customer_Name in Customers:
                Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] += 1
                Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount
            else:
                Customers[Customer_Name] = {}
                Customers[Customer_Name]['Address'] = Customers_Address
                Customers[Customer_Name]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
                Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] = 1
                Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = 0
    
            print(Customer_Name, "has ordered {} time(s)".format(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']))
            if Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] == 0:
                print("This is the first time", Customer_Name, "orders")
            else:
                print(Customer_Name, "has spent", Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'], "in total")
    
            print("Current Date is: {}".format(Today_Date))
            Order_Price = float(input("Total amount of order:"))
            Total_Amount = Order_Price + Total_Amount
            if Print_Today != Today_Date:
                print("Total amount of orders today is: ", float(Total_Amount))
            answer1 = input("Send another order? (Y/N)").lower()
            if answer1 == "y":
                process2 = True
            else:
                process2 = False
        LengthCustomersList = len(CustomerList)
        length += 1
        inlist += 1
        file = open('CustomerNames.txt', 'w')
        file.write(str(CustomerList[0:]) + '\n')  # TAKE CARE FOR DUPLICATE NAMES FROM SAME ADDRESS
        file.close()
        file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'a')
        file1.write(Customer_Name + " has ordered " + str(
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']) + " times in total\n")  # FIX DUPLICATES SAME NAME SAME ADDRESS
        file1.close()
        with open('data_entered.csv', 'a') as f:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Customer Name', 'Customer Address', 'Customer ID', 'Total Orders',
                                               'Total Amount'])
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            csv_writer.writerows([{'Customer Name': CustomerList[inlist], 'Customer Address': AddressList[inlist],
                                'Customer ID': Customers[Customer_Name]['ID'],
                                'Total Orders': Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'],
                                'Total Amount': Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount']}])
        if int(length) == int(LengthCustomersList):
            process1 = False
```

My idea is to do something like an if statement so when the same Customer ID and the same CustomerName show up in the .csv file , one of them gets deleted, so the file does not contain any duplicates like those in the screenshot above.

Comment: if you can use the `pandas` library I think you could save a lot of trouble with the code.

Comment: Hmm , i have never heard of that . Could you provide a link ?

Comment: pandas.pydata.org

Comment: I see that I have to do an installation. This is an assignment I have to send to my professor , if I use pandas library, does my professor also have to install it (if he doesn't already have it) for it to work?

Comment: @Kygo `pandas` is one of the most popular python libraries in existence, making up ~10% of all python StackOverflow questions. It's perfect for jobs like this. @Kygo yes, you can sdo `pip install pandas`, but if you downloaded python with Anaconda, then you will already have it installed.

Comment: is there a way to do it without pandas?

Comment: @Kygo, what's the unique key for the spreadsheet data? Customer ID?

Comment: Also, can I get a copy of the raw data (assume i can get in csv file format) instead of the screenshot. You can use dictreader and process them. You shouldnt write after reading each record. You should process through the full file and then write to new file.

Comment: The logic of your program it's wrong. You do an infinite loop, each loop gets data and writes the csv. You cannot delete rows from csv, because you write rows each time they are entered.
Read all the data, and add a condition to quit the loop. Then write the csv.

Comment: @JoeFerndz the exercise i am working on right now , says to generate a Customer ID for each customer so i used the uuid

Comment: @AndrewQ i edited the code and now it doesnt have an infinite loop , but the csv file still has duplicates like those in the screenshot

Comment: recommendation: You can swap this `if answer1 == "y": process2 = True else: process2 = False` with `process2 = answer1 == "y"`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure we are going to eventually solve your question but I wanted to give you some inputs that you can use to fix your code.

1. Use of variable `Today_Date` and `Print_Today` in your code

```
    Today_Date = date.today()
    Print_Today = Today_Date
    
    if Print_Today != Today_Date:
```

These two lines are set to the same value. Later on in the code, you are checking if the are not equal. I checked `Print_Today` and `Today_Date` for reassignment. None occurs. So how do you expect these two variables to have different values?

If this program runs for infinite number of days, it will still NOT change the value of these two variables. The reason is they were defined at the beginning of the program and never changed. You may want to look into it.

2. The use of `Today_Key` in `Dates` dictionary in your code.

```
    Today_Key = date.toordinal(date.today())
    Dates = {}
```

You are using `Today_Key` to count the number of times a customer name was entered. I don't see a point in having `Today_Key` as the key unless you plan to have more than one key in the dictionary. This was set at the beginning of the program and never changed. So what do you intend to do with this key? I don't think you should have that as key. Instead you should just keep track of the customer names. Also, you are not printing or writing this information into a file. Are you intending to use this later in the program? I dont see the value and it may just be using up memory space and processing time.

3. Use of multiple names for Username & Password.

You have created 6 variables to store username & password. In other places, you are using dictionary. So why are you not taking advantage of the dictionary here?

```
FirstEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee1"
FirstEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop1"
SecondEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee2"
SecondEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop2"
ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee3"
ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop3"
```

Instead of these, can't you just define a dict variable and check for the value as shown below?

```
UserLogin = {"coffee1":"coffeeshop1", "coffee2": "coffeeshop2", "coffee3": "coffeeshop3"}
username = password = ''
while True:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    if (username in UserLogin) and (UserLogin[username] == password):
        print("Login Successful")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Login. Try again")
```

4. For your customer name counter portion, try this. I dont think you are actually doing anything with the counter. If you are, this code is much simpler.

```
    CustomerCounts = defaultdict(int)
    while True:
        Customer_Name = input("Customer's Name:")
        CustomerList.append(Customer_Name)
        Customers_Address = input("Customer's Address:")
        AddressList.append(Customers_Address)
        CustomerCounts[Customer_Name] += 1
```

similarly, try using defaultdict and reduce a lot of code you have written. In the end, there is lot of code optimization and logic corrections you can do. However, it does not solve the infinite loop situation.

Comment: I will answer you, cause I have some chores and things to do.